# display numbers till entered number (in console c#)

Tags: console, limit

how can i display the numbers till the entered by user number?
for example, if the input is 9, it displays 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
MSVisual studio, c#
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
int input = Int32.parseInt(Console.ReadLine());
for(int i = 0; i<=input; i++){ //for loop
  Console.WriteLine(i);        
}
```